# Embedding url in Sencha store giving error

Tags: xml, json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using a JSON proxy and passing a url as a parameter in the store.Now the data that i was receiving originally was in xml format.As sencha does not allow xml response on cross domain and json proxy does not support xml responses I am using YQL service which converts my xml response to json and shows me correct json data when i check the url in the browser.However when I am trying to pass the url as a parameter I am getting error.The url is as given

```
'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sdcountyemergency.com%2Fhandlers%2Fshelterlocations.ashx'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&q=ask%27&callback='
```

Is there any solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple single-quote marks in your URL. If that's not an error on your part, you need to either:

1. Wrap the entire string in double quotes, or
2. URL-encode the string, or
3. string-escape those characters